# PHP and AJAX pagination

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I trying to implement ajax pagination for image thumb gallery but seems I can understand this well and I miss something.
So this is my html

```
<div class="row">                       
    <div class="loading-div"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" ></div>
    <div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

and in the head of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#results" ).load( "fetch_pages.php"); //load initial records

$("#results").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".loading-div").show(); //show loading element
    var page = $(this).attr("data-page"); //get page number from link
    $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php",{"page":page}, function(){ //get content from PHP page
        $(".loading-div").hide(); //once done, hide loading element
    });

});
});
</script>
```

And the php part

```
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
//continue only if $_POST is set and it is a Ajax request
if(isset($_GET['album_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['album_id'])){
        $album_id = $_GET['album_id'];

include("config.inc.php");  //include config file
//Get page number from Ajax POST
if(isset($_POST["page"])){
    $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); //filter number
    if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');} //incase of invalid page number
}else{
    $page_number = 1; //if there's no page number, set it to 1
}

//get total number of records from database for pagination
$results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images");
$get_total_rows = $results->fetch_row(); //hold total records in variable
//break records into pages
$total_pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);

//get starting position to fetch the records
$page_position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);

//SQL query that will fetch group of records depending on starting position and item per page. See SQL LIMIT clause
$results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_album = '$album_id' ORDER BY image_id ASC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page");

//Display records fetched from database.

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-ms-6">
                          <div class="g-item">
                                   <img src="../images/gallery/thumb/'.$row['image_name'].'">
                                <a data-rel="lightbox" class="overlay" href="../images/gallery/thumb/'.$row['image_name'].'">
                                    <span>+</span>
                                </a>
                       </div> <!-- /.g-item -->
              </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->';
}   

echo '<div align="center">';
echo paginate_function($item_per_page, $page_number, $get_total_rows[0], $total_pages);
echo '</div>';

} 
} else { echo "no items in this album"; }
```

What I try to achieve is when user click on category ( `which already is working fine` ) to load new page with the images from this category (album) and then there are few thumbs and pagination. 
When I remove the part with $_GET is work but I need to get album_id in order to show only those images. Here is the button on the index page

```
gallery.php?album_id='.$row['album_id'].'
```

Tutorial that I follow is [from here](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/ajax-pagination-with-jquery-php)

There is no errors and no images on the page..

Answer (score 0):

Well you do not send the album_id to your script

```
$("#results").load("fetch_pages.php",{"page":page},
```

You only add the page which should be loaded not the album id.

Second you send the data via post. $_GET is always empty in post requests.

Comment: Thank's for your answer.I don't understand exactly how to send album_id. I mean on the albums I have `album_id=1, album_id=2`. So if I click album_id=1 it's open page gallery.php and then how to pass the ID to the script?

Comment: Just add the album id to your data array. Something like `{"page": page, "album_id": myalbumid}

Comment: Where should be `js` script in first index page or in second where will be loaded images in `gallery.php`? Also I've tried something like `{"page":page", "album_id": album_id}` and doesn't seem to be right. and in `fetch_pages.php` I have added `$album_id = $_POST['album_id'];` since is POST.